# Efficiently integrate detection results

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, face-detection, viola-jones

In [Viola and Jones's](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/EE148-2005-Spring/pprs/viola04ijcv.pdf) paper, section 5.6 the authors mention they integrate multiple detections their detector make while scanning for faces in images. In this case, a detection is simply a rectangular region positioned over an image where the detector considered that a face exist. Integration is the simple combination of overlapping rectangular regions. This is useful because the detector may produce many detections around a single face while scanning an image.

Note that many detections may not overlap others, so it is possible to have more than one integrated detection. For instance, consider an image with 2 faces, `A` and `B`. Consider also that the image has regions `C` and `D` that are very similar to faces, but are not faces. In this case, the detector may produce 3 overlapping detections for face `A`, 5 overlapping detections for face `B`, 1 detection for region `C` and 10 overlapping detections for region `D`. Considering that the detections for a region do not overlap with detections of another region, the integration procedure should produce a single final detection for face `A`, another detection for face `B`, another single detection for region `C` and another single detection for region `D`. Those 4 integrated detections should be displayed to the user.

So, to integrate the detections, it is necessary to separate them into subsets of overlapping detections. But we should add to a subset any detection that overlaps with any detection already in the subset. Simple iterations over a list of detections will perform poorly (Ω(n²)).

My question is then: **what data structure and algorithm allows the quick integration of detections?** Please, do provide some literary evidence (paper or book reference, for instance) about the approach you're mentioning.

Comment: Which errors would you most like to tolerate?

Comment: @stark Not sure what you mean. According to the paper, all detections that overlap are integrated into a single detection. This happens with true positives and false positives.

Comment: If they are all equally valid then just choose one at random

Comment: I just improved the question, since I wasn't making my point clear.

Comment: OpenCV uses a function called `groupRectangles()` for this task, which at its core uses K-means clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Have you benchmarked?

Are overlapping detections really the performance bottleneck? Don't optimize too early.

Have you considered sorting the rectangles data by x coordinate? Overlap detection should be fairly cheap then.

Answer (score -1):

I think R-trees should solve the problem.

Comment: R trees are used for spatial indexing. In your case, each node will be a rectangle. You can make an R tree from that. This is a nice link http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/454/jpei/slides/R-Tree.pdf

Comment: I doubt R-trees will help anything. They are a disk-oriented data structure. Within each page, you will still have O(n^2) comparisons, and in 8k pages you can fit a lot of pixel rectangles...